# Android Swipe to refresh bug

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have successfully implemented the swipe to refresh function with RecyclerView and it worked fine.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipyRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(getRefreshLayoutId());
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipyRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection swipyRefreshLayoutDirection) {
            doRefreshTask();
        }
    });
}

protected void onRefreshComplete() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    completeRefresh();
}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_recycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

However, if I am pulling down the refresh button and release and in the mean time (before the onRefreshListener triggered) I pull down again, then the refresh button stopped in the middle of the screen and do nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Gmail somehow can disable the "malicious" pull down action.

The library I use: 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

Comment: You should add your code so others can review it.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, code is added.

Comment: I will add that this is a legitimate bug im having similar issues in an earlier android device.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you find any luck with it?

Comment: I end up using a third party library which has the same effect: [link](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that this is a bug in support design library 23.0.1, rollback to version 22.2.1 will not have this issue.